# Find text in array of object and return only relevant items (aggregate & project)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to query mongoDB (mongoose) in very specific way. Here is the challenge:

**My schema:**

```
const eventSchema = new Schema(
 { name: { type: 'String' },
    sessions: {
       type: [
        {
            id: { type: 'Number' },
            name: { type: 'String' }
        }
    ]
}
});
```

**Actual data**

```
{"_id": "234", "name": "ng-nl", "sessions":[
        {"id":"1", "name": "Testing Angular 4 Workshop"},
        {"id":"2", "name": "Angular 4 and Firebase"}
                ]}

{"_id": "896", "name": "ng-conf 2037", "sessions":[
        {"id":"1", "name": "How Elm Powers React"},
        {"id":"2", "name": "Angular and React together"}
                ]}
```

**The challenge:**
When searching for string "angular"
I would like to get following data (the structure may be different):

```
{"_id": "234", session: {"id":"1", "name": "Testing Angular 4 Workshop"}}
{"_id": "234", session: {"id":"2", "name": "Angular 4 and Firebase"}}
{"_id": "896", session: {"id":"2", "name": "Angular and React together"}}
```

I've tried 
{sessions.name: {$regex: 'angular', $options: 'i'}}
works correctly but returns full objects, I need only relevant sessions.

I've thought to do something with

```
db.test.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         sessions: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$sessions",
               as: "session",
               cond: { $match: [{"$$session.name": {$regex: 'albert', $options: 'i'}}] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

But I have an error "MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$match'".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$unwind` and `$match` to get the expected result like this:

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$sessions"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "sessions.name": {
        "$regex": "angular",
        "$options": "i"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Output**

```
[
  { "_id": "234","name": "ng-nl","sessions": {"id": "1","name": "Testing Angular 4 Workshop"}},
  {"_id": "234", "name": "ng-nl","sessions": {"id": "2","name": "Angular 4 and Firebase"}},
  { "_id": "896","name": "ng-conf 2037","sessions": {"id": "2","name": "Angular and React together"}}
]
```

In your expected output above, you have excluded outer name field. If you don't want to show the all fields in the result you can use `$project` like this:

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$sessions"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "sessions.name": {
        "$regex": "angular",
        "$options": "i"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$_id",
      "sessions": 1
    }
  }
])
```

**Output**

```
[
  {"_id": "234","sessions": {"id": "1","name": "Testing Angular 4 Workshop"}},
  {"_id": "234","sessions": {"id": "2","name": "Angular 4 and Firebase"}},
  {"_id": "896","sessions": {"id": "2","name": "Angular and React together"}}
]
```

Comment: Off topic: Seems to me that NO SQL much harder than "good, old" SQL. :) . Or it's a matter of experience.

Comment: This is a much more difficult question than it sounds. If you are new to Database concept, SOL is more likely to be easier than NoSQL. 
But don't worry once you get used to, you will find NoSQL easier and simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Try $unwind like this

```
db.test.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         sessions: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$sessions",
               as: "session",
               cond: { $match: [{"$$session.name": {$regex: 'albert', $options: 'i'}}] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $unwind:"$sessions"
   }
])
```

Comment: Failed to execute script.

Error: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$match'",
 "code" : 168,
 "codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator",
} : aggregate failed 
Details:
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:18:14
_assertCommandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:534:17
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:618:16
DB.prototype._runAggregate@src/mongo/shell/db.js:260:9
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1062:12
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@:1:355
@(shell):1:1